# Authentication system (no browser) with mail verification

Tags: beginner, php, html, mysql, mysqli

I made an authentication system for my software (no browser is used) that works like this:

- User receives a Key on it's mail after buying the software
- User registers account using that key and inputs username, mail, password.
- **registration.php** checks if the format is correct then sends an email with a confirmation code using a template and inserts the values into DB (verify table).
- The HTML template contains username (from user input), 2 images from the same directory as the registration.php and the **template2.html** and a button with a get like this: *www.mysite.com/activate.php?id=$serial&conf=$confirmation_code*.
- **activate.php** checks if everything is valid and then inserts the verify table's row into accounts table. (after it is inserted into accounts table, it becomes a valid account).

Everything works as expected (I'm still making the login.php).

## Why I'm posting this here:

As a beginner (this is the first php, mysql and html thing I do) I know there is a lot of things that can be improved. My goal is to make it as secure as possible, I followed OWASP as much as I could and at the same time I read a lot on Stack Overflow and Security.Stackexchange.

## Here is my code:

#### registration.php

```
<?php
$CurrentVersionHash="asd123";
$CurrentVersion="alpha1";
$CurrentHash="asd123";
$serial_length="10";
$memory_cost="31250";
$time_cost="10";
$threads="1";
require 'mail.php';

if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) // Check if Post is not empty
{
    $hash = $_POST['exe'];
    $pw = $_POST['pass'];
    $user = $_POST['name'];
    $version = $_POST['ver'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $confirm = $_POST['pass2'];
    $serial = $_POST['key'];
    if ( empty($hash) or empty($version))
        return;
    if ( $hash<>$CurrentHash) // Check if file Hash is valid
    {
        if ( $version<>$CurrentVersionHash ) // Check if it's because it's outdated
        {
            echo "Old exe";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Exe not valid";
        }
        return;
    }
    // Checking if there is any problem in the format
    if ( (empty( $user )) or ( strlen( $user ) < 6 ) or ( strlen( $user ) > 254 ) or ( ! ctype_alnum ( $user )) )
    {
        echo "Error"; 
        return;
    }
    if ( (empty( $pw)) or (strlen($pw) < 10) or (strlen($pw) > 254) or (! preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pw)) or ( !preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $pw )) or ( !preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $pw )) )
    { 
        echo "Error"; 
        return;
    }
    if ( $pw != $confirm  or empty( $confirm ) )
    { 
        echo "Error"; 
        return;
    }
    if (( empty( $email )) or ( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) or (strlen($email) > 254) )
    { 
        echo "Error"; 
        return;
    }
    if ( ( empty( $serial ) ) or ( strlen( $serial ) <> $serial_length ) )
    { 
        echo "Error"; 
        return;
    }
    // Check if Serial exists and is not already taken
    $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM acc WHERE serial=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $serial);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
    $result = $result->fetch_array();
    // If Serial doesn't exist or is already taken
    if ( ($num_of_rows==0) or ( ! empty( $result['username'] )) ) 
    {
        echo "Invalid Serial";
        $error=1;
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM verify WHERE serial=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $serial);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
    $result = $result->fetch_array();
    // If Serial is on verify DB (means that someone already registered using it)
    if ( ($num_of_rows<>0) and ($error<>1) )
    {
        echo "Invalid Serial";
        $error=1;
    }
    if ($error<>1)
    {
        // Check if Username or E-mail is not already taken
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM acc WHERE username= ? OR email= ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
        $result = $result->fetch_array();
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM verify WHERE username= ? OR email= ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result2 = $stmt->get_result();
        $num_of_rows2 = $result2->num_rows;
        $result2 = $result2->fetch_array();
        if ( ($num_of_rows) or ($num_of_rows2) ) // If user or email already exists on verify and acc DB
        {
            if ( (strcasecmp($result['username'], $user) == 0) or (strcasecmp($result2['username'], $user) == 0) ) // If user already exists
            {
                echo "Username in use";
            }
            else if ( (strcasecmp($result['email'], $email) == 0) or (strcasecmp($result2['email'], $email) == 0) )// If e-mail is already taken
            {
                echo "Email in use";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Do registration
            $password = password_hash( $pw, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID, [
                    'memory_cost' => $memory_cost,
                    'time_cost'   => $time_cost,
                    'threads'     => $threads,
            ]);
            $rand_id = random_int(-10000, 10000);
            $rand_secret = random_str(32);
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO verify (username, password, email, serial, rand_id, rand_secret) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $user, $password, $email, $serial, $rand_id, $rand_secret);
            $stmt->execute();
            $confirmation_code = hash_hmac('sha256', $rand_id, $rand_secret);
            $variables = array();
            $variables['User'] = $user;
            $variables['Serial'] = $serial;
            $variables['Code'] = $confirmation_code;
            $template = file_get_contents("template2.html");
            foreach($variables as $key => $value)
            {
                $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value, $template);
            }
            $mail->addAddress($email, $user);
            $mail->msgHTML($template, __DIR__);
            $mail->AltBody = "You can activate your account here: www.mysite.com/activate.php?id=$serial&conf=$confirmation_code";
            if (!$mail->send()) 
            {
                echo 'error, mail not delivered';
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Registration OK! mail sent";
            }
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
    return;
}

function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
{
    $pieces = [];
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $pieces []= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
    return implode('', $pieces);
}
?>
```

#### activate.php

```
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_GET ) )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['id']) and isset($_GET['conf']) )
    {
        $key=$_GET['id'];
        $code=$_GET['conf'];
        $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM verify WHERE serial=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
        $result = $result->fetch_array();
        // If Serial doesn't exist or is already taken
        if ( ($num_of_rows==0) or ( empty( $result['username'] )) or ( empty( $result['rand_id'] )) or ( empty( $result['rand_secret'] )) )
        {
            $error=1;
            echo "Invalid code";
        }
        if ( $error<>1 )
        {
            $rand_id = $result['rand_id'];
            $rand_secret = $result['rand_secret'];
            $confirmation_code = hash_hmac('sha256', $rand_id, $rand_secret);
            if ($confirmation_code == $code)
            {
                $user=$result['username'];
                $password=$result['password'];
                $email=$result['email'];
                $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET username = ?, password = ?, email = ? WHERE Serial = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $user, $password, $email, $key);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE from verify WHERE serial = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo "Account activated";
            }
            else
            {
                $error=1;
                echo "Invalid code";
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $con->close();
        return;
    }
}

function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
{
    $pieces = [];
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $pieces []= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
    return implode('', $pieces);
}
?>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtphost';
$mail->Port = port;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mymail';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
$mail->setFrom('mymail', 'myname');
$mail->addReplyTo('mysupportmail', 'myname');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/logo.png', 'mylogo');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/gif.gif', 'mygif');
$mail->Subject = "Activation for account";
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry, I will read that page. Thanks for changing it back to normal

Answer (score 2):

Overall this is a lot of procedural code to process. That is fine to use but I would suggest you look into an MVC structure, or at least OOP - abstracting bits of code into controller methods and other functions or static methods that can be called by these pages, as well as tested by unit tests. I know that might be a lot to expect from a beginner but it is worth learning about and utilizing.

The code already uses [`require`](http://php.net/require) for `mail.php`. I would suggest abstracting the repeated function `random_str()` into a single file,  along with any other common functions, and then using `require` to include it wherever necessary, which would be inline with the [***D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself* principle](https://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/). That way any updates to the function can be done in one spot instead of multiple. If you use OOP/MVC techniques as recommended above, that function could be static method of a class - e.g. `Authentication`, `AuthenticationController`, `Registration`, `RegistrationController`, etc.

Also, those variables listed at the top of *registration.php* which do not change can be stored as constants - either with [`define()`](http://php.net/define) or the [`const`](http://php.net/const) keyword - especially the latter if there is an appropriate class created to associate those with. And a common convention for constants is for them to be named using all capitalized letters. While this is not a requirement, many believe it helps when reading the code to distinguish constants from other values.

The sequential queries in *registration.php* i.e. `"SELECT * FROM acc WHERE serial=?"` and `"SELECT verify FROM acc WHERE serial=?"` make me wonder if `serial` is a primary/foreign key of one or both of those tables, and if those two queries could be combined into a single query where the tables are `JOIN`ed one those fields.

It would be a good habit to use the [Identical comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (i.e. `===`) where appropriate instead of the Equal comparison operator (i.e. `==`) unless you are sure that type-juggling is fine for your use case. And the same is true for the Not Identical Operator (i.e. `!==`) vs Not equal (i.e. `!=` or `<>`).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will update the code with what you wrote after the first paragraph. About MVC structure, that's something new for me, I will start reading about it and will do my best to adapt my code to it. From what I read (only 1 page) it is Model View and Controllers structure where everything is separated. How would I achieve this, using different files or something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: About the Serial thing being checked on both tables it's because when a user tries to register with a serial, I want to check if there is any valid account with that serial or any non-activated account with that serial. I still have to add something to clear the row in verify table if the user doesn't confirm his/her account in X amount of time (like 1 week or something).

Comment: I can't edit my comments so, about editing the post. Thanks to Ludisposed for telling me that it goes against Code Review. I already applied those changes in my code and everything is working fine. I'm still learning about OOP.
Still I'm worried about the security, I already used prepared statements for almost everything, but I'm worried about the mail thing. Username and email are used and I don't know what to do with those.